# Measuring vertical movement of non-fixed Android device

Tags: android-sensors, sensor-fusion

My goal is to make an Android mobile app (SDK16+) that measures road quality while riding a bike.

I have found a [Sensor fusion demo for Android](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/overview) that I assume will do all the measurements for me.

How can I get only the vertical movement when the phone is not fixed in a certain orientation?

Comment: Can you assume that the phone is held in the same orientation? From still, you can measure 3D gravity and obtain angle, then work with that. It will not work for very steep climbs

Comment: @djechelon No, I need to be able to detect bumps and potholes regardless from mobile device state position.

Comment: You may want to detect steep accelerations "in modulus". It's a 3D geometry problem. Basically you may want to compute the modulus of each sensor detection and then compare to the next. If they are >= than a fixed treshold you may have your bump. Make lots of tests and visual analyses on your data

Comment: @djechelon Yes, I could detect only steep accelerations but I think if cyclist makes sharp turn it counts as steep acceleration - bump. But that is not what I want.

Comment: Are you sure? I think that a bump is more sharp than a steer. That is why I suggested you to work on real data and classificate it

Comment: I also think bumps will be much sharper than steering motions. Even though the overall motion of the steer is much bigger, the momentaneous acceleration will be higher in the case of the smaller bumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem**

The problem here is that you have two systems of coordinates, the dx, dy, dz, of your device and the wX, wY, wZ of the world around you. The relationship between the two changes as you move your device around.

Another way to formulate your question would be to say:

> Given a sensor reading [dx, dy, dz], how do I find the component of the reading which is parallel to wZ?

**A solution**

Luckily, the orientation sensors (such as Android's own `ROTATION_VECTOR` sensor) provide the tools for transformation between these two coordinate systems.

For example, the output of the `ROTATION_VECTOR`sensor comes in the form of an [axis-angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) representation of the rotation your device has from some certain "base" rotation fixed in the world frame (see also: [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)).

Android the provides the method `SensorManager#getRotationMatrixFromVector(float[] R, float[] rotationVector)`, which takes axis-angle representation from your sensor and translates it into a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). A rotation matrix is used to transform a vector given in one frame of reference to another (in this case [ World -> Device ]).

Now, you want to transform a measurement in the device frame into the world frame? No problem. One nifty characteristic of rotation matrices is that the inverse of the rotation matrix is the rotation matrix of the opposite transformation ([Device -> World] in our case). Another, even niftier thing is that the inverse of a rotation matrix simply is it's transpose.

So, your code could follow the lines of:

```
public void findVerticalComponentOfSensorValue() {
    float[] rotationVectorOutput = ... // Get latest value from ROTATION_VECTOR sensor
    float[] accelerometerValue = ... // Get latest value from ACCELEROMETER sensor

    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9]; // Both 9 and 16 works, depending on what you're doing with it
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, rotationVectorOutput);

    float[] accelerationInWorldFrame = matrixMult(
            matrixTranspose(rotationMatrix), 
            accelerometerValue); 
    // Make your own methods for the matrix operations or find an existing library

    accelerationInWorldFrame[2] // This is your vertical acceleration
}
```

Now, I'm not saying this is the best possible solution, but it should do what you're after.

**Disclaimer**

Strapping a device that uses sensor fusion including a magnetometer to a metal frame may produce inconsistent results. Since your compass heading doesn't matter here, I'd suggest using a sensor fusion method that doesn't involve the magnetometer.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got a feeling I will be able to do this.

Comment: Good luck! Dealing with rotations can be tricky sometimes, but I'm sure you'll work it out.

Comment: I think I did all you said, but result of accelerationInWorldFrame is the same as acceleration. http://pastebin.com/HVPRb9Sg

Comment: Have a look at your `rotationVectorOutput` values and make sure they're something else than [0, 0, 0, 1] (no rotation). If there was some other error I would expect the values to be bonkers, but not exactly the same.

Comment: I take only xyz from rotationVectorOutput. If i take all four don't I need rotationMatrix = new float[16]?

Comment: Only taking xyz means you have a zero rotation around whatever axis xyz forms. As such you would get the same values. Use all four and the 3x3 matrix... The 4x4 is (I believe) for encoding more complex motions than rotation (google Affine transformation).

Comment: Still no luck. I use this project - http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/sensor/android-accelerometer-example/ and implemented rotation vector. Here is my changes - http://pastebin.com/pApmBKy6 (sorry, code is messy). If you have time you can run project on your phone and test. Only thing I noticed is that  accelerationInWorldFrame[0] is opposite for accelerometerValue[0], for example 2 comes -2.

Comment: I'll take a closer look later if you haven't solved it. A question though, why are you using the difference in accelerometer readings? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: It removes default 9,8m/s^2

Comment: Just take that off your vertical acceleration later instead. Using only the change removes a whole lot more than that.

Comment: Still accelerationInWorldFrame values are the same as orginal

Comment: Could you go through with debugger and write down values for `rotationVectorOutput`, `accelerometerValue`, `rotationMatrix`, `accelerationInWorldFrame`? Would help to figure out what's going on (when `rotationVectorOutput` is something else than [0, 0, 0, 1] and `accelerometerValue` is non-zero)