# Calculate vertical acceleration from sensor data

Tags: android, accelerometer, linear-algebra, android-sensors, gyroscope

I'm using `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` and `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` to read the rotation vector and accelerometer values from the device's sensors.

I want to use this data to calculate the vertical acceleration of the phone - i.e. regardless of how the phone is rotated, I want to be able to read the acceleration in the up/down direction relative to the ground.

How can I accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

Right now I have this code:

```
private double getVerticalAcceleration(){
    // Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268852/measuring-vertical-movement-of-non-fixed-android-device
    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9]; // Both 9 and 16 works, depending on what you're doing with it
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, rotationVector);

    float[] accelerationInWorldFrame = matrixMult3x9(
            accelerometerValues,
            rotationMatrixTranspose(rotationMatrix)
    );


    return accelerationInWorldFrame[2];
}



private float[] matrixMult3x9(float[] a, float[] b){
    float[] result = new float[3];
    result[0] = a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[3] + a[2]*b[6];
    result[1] = a[0]*b[1] + a[1]*b[4] + a[2]*b[7];
    result[2] = a[0]*b[2] + a[1]*b[5] + a[2]*b[8];
    return result;
}


private float[] rotationMatrixTranspose(float[] rotationMatrix){
    float[] result = new float[9];
    result[0] = rotationMatrix[0];
    result[1] = rotationMatrix[3];
    result[2] = rotationMatrix[6];
    result[3] = rotationMatrix[1];
    result[4] = rotationMatrix[4];
    result[5] = rotationMatrix[7];
    result[6] = rotationMatrix[2];
    result[7] = rotationMatrix[5];
    result[8] = rotationMatrix[8];
    return result;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working very well, because if I hold the phone upright for example, the difference between the raw Y-accelerometer value and the value returned from `getVerticalAcceleration()` should be `0` (or very close to 0), but I'm seeing all sorts of values.

Comment: You need to convert the acceleration to world coordinate and then subtract out gravity.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do with the code I posted, but it doesn't seem to be 100% correct (and `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` automatically subtracts gravity).

Comment: You should not transpose the rotation matrix. The rotation matrix is a change of basis matrix from device coordinate to world coordinate. when you transpose it, it is the inverse so that is why your number does not make sense.